# Fastest way to insert and read 50,000+ records into Azure CosmosDB with Node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

as the title suggests I need to insert 50,000+ records into Azure CosmosDb running SQL mode and read them later on again programatically with Node. C# has the BulkExecutor, but what's the best and fastest way in Node?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the short term, you could implement some of the same logic in the Bulk Executor library in Node.js. Biggest things are having to understand our underlying physical partitioning layer, which isn't easy.

In the mid-to-long term, we'll be adding bulk operation support to Node.js/Python. For now, you might save yourself some time making due with Java/.NET library until then.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped for, but many thanks for the information nethertheless :-)